# What should be done about this wrong answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, wrong-answers

[mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) has raised concerns about correctness of this particular answer:

[How to remove part of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192170/how-to-remove-part-of-a-string/2192217#2192217)

The answer mentions regex as a solution to remove a part of a string in PHP. As shown by mickmackusa, the answer is wrong and doesn't do what it claims should happen.

The answer has a score of +17/-4 which is very worrying when it comes to a completely wrong answer.

It [could be fixed](https://3v4l.org/J95FT) with lookahead and lookbehind, but that would be putting words into the author's mouth and forcibly fixing the broken answer.

The whole Q&A is not very clear, but people have found it useful over the years nonetheless, so there's probably no reason to close or delete the question.

Should the answer be deleted or fixed? If it should be deleted, how can this be done by normal users when the answer is positively scored?

Comment: My disgust with the page in general is that the FGITW answerers did not understand the Unclear question, then I assume that other answers merely drew the meaning of the question from existing answers instead of logically reading the question requirements.  When volunteers are earning heaps of "trust points" from completely incorrect answers, Stackoverflow is failing to provide value to researchers.  The page should have been closed as Unclear in its first two minutes, not answered. Now we have a completely broken page with illogical answers.  We have better content elsewhere.

Comment: The OP has abandoned the question/site.  The page in question can be safely removed without Stackoverflow losing ANY value. All old rep is now locked in, so no users will be hard-done-by. My earlier Unclear vote has aged-away.  I cannot yet revote to close.

Comment: Well, we (users with < 20k reps) can't vote to delete an answer anyway, so it is up to trusted users to do that (when the answer has a negative score). A flag won't help here. So a downvote is the only thing we could do with this answer and maybe post a new and corrected answer with regex.

Comment: The answer author is active, and the first comment addressing the answer's problems was posted only four hours ago. Why don't give the post author a chance to fix the question or at least respond to the comment?

Comment: If a question or a answer has errors correct them, the review proce3ss will imrove the anser you give if necessaey. It is a normal edit, like it happens dailay, so change the thing and see if the author reacts at all

Answer (score 10):

This is a situation that pretty much justifies creating artificial attention and establishing a voting ring.

Gather a group of experts in the relevant technology (say, a suitable SO chatroom), bring the answer there for discussion. Once it is clear that the answer is problematic, those users can act accordingly, usually by downvoting it. Other actions may also take place:

- Voting to close the question if it should not have been answered in the first place;
- Voting to delete said question if, once closed, adds absolutely **no value** to the site;
- Upvoting better alternative answers, to create further contrast;
- Create a new answer which corrects the flaws of the other one.

We will be witnessing a similar effect here anyway, because of this Meta question.

It is non-normative to vote to delete answers just because they are wrong, but with enough effort, we can bring a strong enough signal that people should be avoiding it. Use your downvotes, folks. You'll be helping all future visitors who come across it.

Comment: I suspect the Meta effect will now stall with this page closed.